# LINQ vs PLINQ: When does overhead outweigh benefits?

Tags: c#-4.0, repository-pattern, asp.net-4.0, plinq

I am working on projects basically ecommerce type. our architect has got instructions from client to use PLINQ as its much more beneficial than LINQ, as they works in parallel and uses all cores of the processors, resulting in quick responses. Client suggestion is PLINQ + Repository if possible.

So I just want to know, which one is good to follow in small and medium app. Is it feasible to use Plinq + Repository. As per my findings, I found Plinq has more overhead than linq if we are not handling the stuffs properly. Please help me.

Comment: Changed parallel-linq tag to plinq tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to answer this question without knowing far more details about your application. PLINQ has overhead to fan out the workload to worker threads and then coordinate the work amongst them. If you are processing hundreds of thousands of entities and have a meaningful amount of work to do for each one, then yes it can benefit. In the end, the only way to *really* know if PLINQ will benefit you is to profile using a realistic data set.

Answer (score 1):

When a `for` loop has a small body, it might perform more slowly than the equivalent sequential loop. Slower performance is caused by the overhead involved in partitioning the data and the cost of invoking a delegate on each loop iteration. To address such scenarios, the `Partitioner` class provides the `Partitioner.Create` method, which enables you to provide a sequential loop for the delegate body, so that the delegate is invoked only once per partition, instead of once per iteration.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx).

This applies to PLINQ.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx) for PLINQ.

Answer (score 0):

LOL.

> *[He who pays the piper calls the tune](http://www.blurtit.com/q669112.html)*

Generally though, this is an engineering issue. Talk to the architects and clients and work out what what metrics they will be using to measure the performance of the deliverables.

Then using these metrics find the optimal solution Linq, PLinq or other and then report back your findings.

In the main all technologies are good for something and the size of the app is measured in different ways. So your term 'small' is meaningless.

Comment: I do not use PLINQ. but I tried Parallel.foreach in my project. I tried to use Parallel.foreach to replace foreach. For unit testing, it is ok. and it is faster. But the problem is that I found the thread number keeps increase for some situation. and I have no idea how to control it. and I have to change it back.